# Java Generic Question

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types

The following code compiles but if I uncomment the commented line, it does not and I am confused why. HashMap does extend AbstractMap and the first line where map is declared compiles fine.

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, ? extends AbstractMap<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        //map.put("one", new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
}
```

And, I know the "right way" is this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        map.put("one", new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first code is unsafe - imagine you're actually written:

```
HashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>> strongMap = 
    new HashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, ? extends AbstractMap<String, String>> map = strongMap;
```

Now:

```
map.put("one", new HashMap<String, String>());
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> x = strongMap.get("one");
```

We *should* have a `ConcurrentHashMap` - but in reality we've only got a `HashMap`.

This is actually a lot simpler to explain if we reduce the amount of generics going on... your scenario is *really* equivalent to (say):

```
List<? extends Fruit> list = new List<Apple>();
list.add(new Apple());
```

which looks okay, until you consider that it's equivalent in validity (as far as the *compiler* is concerned) to:

```
List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
List<? extends Fruit> list = apples;
list.add(new Orange());
Apple apple = list.get(0); // Should be okay... but element 0 is an Orange!
```

which is obviously *not* okay. The compiler has to treat the two in the same way, so it makes both of them invalid.

Comment: Hi jon. Can you explain ? why is it not safe? It seemed to me that the orange example should work. it should add an orange to the list of fruits.

Comment: and most important what is the solution if we want to hold a generic list of fruits?

Comment: @user450602: But it's not *actually* a list of fruits - it's a `List<Apple>`. Java can't tell because of type erasure, but that's what it was created as. I'll edit the example to show more of why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @user450602: It depends what you mean by "a generic list of fruits" - if you mean a list you can add any fruit to, and you only know later that what's in there is a fruit, you'd just use `List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<Fruit>();`.

Comment: @user450602: For times when you *don't* need that. For example, if you pass a `List<? extends Fruit>` into a method, it can *get* any value and know it's a `Fruit`, which may be all it needs. If you pass in a `List<? super Fruit>` then it knows it can *add* any fruit, but doesn't know what type it could get from the list.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jon's excellent answer, see also this [question on PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) which covers a lot of the same ground.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the really technical explanation I would recommend reading through these slides in  [component based software](http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDD05/lectures/lectures.en.shtml) for a complete picture of the issue since your little problem has immense ramifications on a large scale :)

The real terms are *contravariance* and *covariance*. Search for them in [these slides](http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDD05/lectures/TDDD05_Lecture02_1slides.pdf) regarding OO-design and its limitations in larger systems.

Your problem is a mix of these with some *generics* mixed in :)

Ie, your contract (*something which is a fruit of something more specific than a fruit*) specifies that the list must be able to keep **all** kinds of fruit, but you create a list only capable of holding a certain kind of fruit (*apples or something more specific than an apple*), which according to me should raise a compiler error, but the Java-compiler is too nice and *generics* is not properly implemented in Java (sementically, and from an introspection point-of-view).

The container instance can be covariant or invariant to the container type/class but the containee of the instance must be the invariant to the containee type/class.

A concrete example:

```
List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

A general example:

```
ConatainerType<ElementOfList> list = new MoreSpecificContainerType<ElementOfList>();
```

**ElementOfList** must fulfill both covariance and contravariance since objects can both be put into (covariance) and retrieved (contravariance) and that leaves only invariance, ie the same type/class.

This was a really long answer, but I hope it helps someone who asks a similar question in the future.