# Java arraylist question (capture?)

Tags: java, arraylist

In java I have an arraylist that holds the following

```
 List<IMyInterface>
```

I am returning it in a function

```
List<? extends IMyInterface> getList()
```

Now I wanna do the following

```
getList().add(MyElement)
```

where MyElement extends the interface.

What I get is a compile error that the method was expecting something else.
here it is:

add (**capture** ) in list cannot be aplied to (MyElement).

.   though MyElement extends th IMyInterface

BTW: What is the word Capture in bold ? 
Thanks.

Comment: [Answer for similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974065/java-generic-question/5974147#5974147)

Comment: Is the return type of getList missing List?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. My Bad in copying. Fixed. And thanks for the notice. Question still remains.

Comment: John . This link is really great. John skeet has in his comment just the answer to my question. It is just that I dont get it :0) . why is working like that not safe  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add is a *consumer* method, it consumes things to be added to the list, so you want any list you add things to to be bounded below (`? super Foo`) rather than above (`Foo extends ?`).

See [this question on PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for more detail.

To make it more concrete, imagine the underlying was `List<MyBetterInterface>`, where `MyBetterInterface` extends `IMyInterface`.  Now you'd still be OK to implement the `getList()` method with the same signature - but it is clearly not valid for a caller to add an object which implements only `IMyInteface` since now you'd have some objects which are not `MyBetterInterface` in there.

So declare it as

```
List<? super IMyInterface> getModifiableList();
```

Comment: I'm not yet convinced this works as expected. The `getList().add(MyElement)` will work, but how do you declare the array list? `List<? super IMyInterface> list = new ArrayList<A>();` will give compilation error (A implements IMyInterface). Could you post a minimal sample?

Comment: Declare it as `ArrayList<IMyInterface>`.